# How to use static variable in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, static

**I am try to load country names and want to save them in static variable. So that I do not hit in my database again and again.**
I am using express Js.
Please suggest me How can i load country name in optimize ways

Comment: share your code

Comment: Sorry I cannot share Company code but it is very similar to replied answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node.js, modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. Every call to import/require will retrieve exactly the same object.
A good way to achieve this is:

app.js

```
var app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app);
var lookup=require('./lookup.js');

server.listen(80, function() {
    //Just one init call
    lookup.callToDb(function(){
       console.log('ready to go!');
    });

});
```

lookup.js

```
callToDb(function (country){
  module.exports=country;
});
```

and wherever you require:
model.js

```
var countryLookup= require('./lookup.js');
```